# Display form values prior to submit for debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I dump all of my form values to an alert box prior to form submit..

I have a simple form like this..  I'd like to see the form values in an alert or console at the time of submit.. I'm using jQuery and jQueryUI (DIALOG) for the form.. but any approach is fin -

```
<div id="highValueSurvey" title="Some More Advanced Questions">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
        <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
            <BR>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""/>
            <BR>        
            <label for="name">Tell us More</label>
            <input type="text" name="more" id="more"/>
            <BR>
            <BR>        
            <label for="name">We want to know even more!!!!</label>
            <input type="textarea" name="evenmore" id="evenmore"/>
            <BR>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Serialized the form and console.log or alert it. Just search for "jQuery serialize".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a very good example right here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
console.info($('#highValueSurvey form').serializeArray())
```

[.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)