# How can I $_POST a form using PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to POST my form using PHP, but for some reason seems impossible, whatever I try to post the message is always empty.

I tried this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="message-container">
    <form id="imageForm" name="form" action="/requests/post_message.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="message-form-content">
            <div class="message-form-header">
                <div class="message-form-user"></div>
                <div class="message-form-private"></div>
                <div class="message-loader" id="post-loader" style="visibility: hidden"><div class="preloader"></div></div>
            </div>

            <div class="message-form-inner">
                <textarea id="post" class="message-form" placeholder="message_form" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="selected-files"><span id="queued-files">0</span> Files selected</div>
            <div class="message-form-input"><input type="text" name="value" id="form-value"></div>

            <div type="button" name="action" class="message-btn button-active" value="Post"><a onclick="startUpload()">Post</a></div>

        </div>
        <iframe id="my_iframe" name="my_iframe" src="" style="display: none"></iframe>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function startUpload() {
    document.getElementById("imageForm").target = "my_iframe";
    document.getElementById("imageForm").submit();
    alert($("#imageForm").serialize()); //for debug
    document.getElementById("post-loader").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

**post_message.php**

```
<?php
include("../includes/config.php");
session_start();

print_r($_POST['message']);
```

From network console I double checked the request and it's correct, I can see `POST with status 200`.

However when I write into the `textarea` and click on the `Post` button, the JS `alert` show me the message correctly instead the `print_r` of my PHP is empty, what's wrong with my form?

Comment: You are sending a GET, and checking for POST variables. Check `$_GET` instead of $_POST.

Comment: alert($("#imageForm").serialize()); //for debug ?

Comment: @VladimirM I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7667608/4458531

Comment: @NineCattoRules what I was hinting is that your id reference is missing the hash tag...

Comment: Do you have jquery included?

Comment: @Nora yes version 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was accepted before it actually resolved the question. I don't know exactly where was the problem located in the end. Originally the asker said the request was being sent by GET according to his browser inspector, but later retracted it.

I only found that this was wrong:

```
alert($("imageForm").serialize()); //for debug
```

should be:

```
 alert($("#imageForm").serialize()); //for debug
```

and better still:

```
 console.log($("#imageForm").serialize()); //for debug
```

Comment: Ok, but what about this?  `<form id="imageForm" name="form" action="/requests/post_message.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Sorry, you are right about that. But you said that in the console you see a GET request with status 200...

Comment: a POST request for the page post_message.php when I click on POST button

Comment: Then as I said, you are sending it via GET, not via POST. Try checking $_GET and see what you get.

Comment: I updated the question, the JS alert show the message correctly instead the PHP print_r is empty

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST)`, and post what you get, please

Comment: This can't be the answer. JavaScript is not sending anything (as in AJAX), it's submitting and existing HTML form that's clearly `method="POST"`. You don't need serialisation for that.